# Sanity CLI - Studio hostname is already taken

Tags: terminal, zsh, sanity

I created a Sanity project on the Sanity studio website manage page at `https://www.sanity.io/manage/personal/projects` from the project dropdown menu via **Select a Project** > **Create new project**:

[image: Sanity studio dropdown]

I also created a local Sanity Studio app in my project's directory via the CLI with `$ sanity init`. The local `sanity.config.js` file in my studio folder and the project at sanity.io have the same projectId value but the Sanity studio on the website shows status "Not deployed":

[image: Studio not deloyed]

When I go to my terminal and type in `sanity deloy` to deploy via the CLI, I'm prompted to enter a studio hostname:

```
Your project has not been assigned a studio hostname.
To deploy your Sanity Studio to our hosted Sanity.Studio service,
you will need one. Please enter the part you want to use.
? Studio hostname (<value>.sanity.studio):
```

When I type in the existing studio hostname for this project I get the error `Studio hostname "<my-hostname-here>" is already taken`

[Documentation for the Sanity CLI](https://www.sanity.io/docs/cli) is very sparse and lacks basic documentation for most of the CLI commands, including this case. How can I connect my existing local studio to the existing project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of combinations for hostnames that I tried and which were not active projects in my dashboard were showing up as taken.

So I assume that the hostname must be a completely unique subdomain, not just for your projects but for all Sanity projects.

I just added my name to the end of the hostname that I wanted and that was accepted and allowed me to deploy.